# Insert code into a method - Java

Tags: java, reflection, code-generation, aspectj

Is there a way to automatically insert code into a method?

I have the following typical field with a getter and setter and I would like to insert the indicated code into the setter method that records if the field was modified as well to insert the indicated "isFirstNameModified" field to also track if the field was modified or not.

```
 public class Person {

      Set<String> updatedFields = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

      String firstName;
      public String getFirstName(){
           return firstName;
      }

      boolean isFirstNameChanged = false;           // This code is inserted later
      public void setFirstName(String firstName){       
           if( !isFirstNameChanged ){               // This code is inserted later
                isFirstNameChanged = true;          // This code is inserted later
                updatedFields.add("firstName");     // This code is inserted later
           }                                        // This code is inserted later
           this.firstName = firstName;
      }
 }
```

I'm also not sure if I can the subset of the method name as a string from inside the method itself as indicated on the line where I add the fieldName as a string into the set of updated fields: `updatedFields.add("firstName");`.  And I'm not sure how to insert fields into a class where I add the boolean field that tracks if the field has been modified or not before (for efficiency to prevent having to manipulate the Set): `boolean isFirstNameChanged = false;`

It seems to most obvious answer to this would be to use code templates inside eclipse, but I'm concerned about having to go back and change the code later.

### Edit:::::::::

**I Should have used this simpler code instead of the example above.  All it does is add the name of the field as a string to a set.**

```
 public class Person {

  Set<String> updatedFields = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

  String firstName;
  public String getFirstName(){
       return firstName;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String firstName){       
       updatedFields.add("firstName");        // This code is inserted later
       this.firstName = firstName;
  }
```

}

Comment: Do you mean dynamically at run time?

Comment: Probably at runtime, but it could even happen at compile time.  I just don't want to code it in such a way that I have to manually re-do everything if I meed to change how it is implemented

Comment: "(for efficiency to prevent having to manipulate the Set)" This would be the last of your efficiency concerns.  It sounds to me like you want to modify a method somehow at runtime?  I would be there are 100 better solutions to your problem.

Comment: @Ed Swangren - What would be a better solution?  I was under the impression that the set has to iterate over the characters in the string in order to hash it and then do an insert somewhere around O(logN)?

Comment: Do you have millions of attributes like `firstName` to optimize the `add` method of the set?

Comment: @True Soft - No, I don't.  But there was some concern about having to do a lot of manipulations on the objects for reporting and what-not.  I should not have included the optimization in the example code.  The key is that I need to mark which fields have been updated so that the datastore knows which properties to overwrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With AspectJ you can modify methods and fields with advises.

My example is written with `@AspectJ` syntax which modifies the code at compile-time or load-time. If you want the modification at runtime, you can use Spring AOP which also supports this `@AspectJ` syntax.

An example with a simple Person class and a stub repository. All information about which fields are updated is handled by an aspect called SetterAspect. It monitors which fields that are updated when the fields is written to.

The other advice in this example is around the update method in the repository. This is to retrieve the data collected from the first aspect.

The Person class:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setFirstName("James");
        person.lastName = "Jameson";

        DtoRepository<Person> personRepository = new DtoRepository<Person>();
        personRepository.update(person);
    }
}
```

The stub repository:

```
public class DtoRepository<T> {

    public void update(T t) {
        System.out.println(t.getClass().getSimpleName() + " updated..");
    }

    public void updatePerson(T t, Set<String> updatedFields) {
        System.out.print("Updated the following fields on " +
            t.getClass().getSimpleName() + " in the repository: "
            + updatedFields);       
    }
}
```

The output for executing the `main()` method in the Person class with AspectJ:

> Updated the following fields on Person
>   in the repository: [lastName,
>   firstName]

Important to note here is that the main() method calls on the `DtoRepository.update(T t)` but the `DtoRepository.update(T t, Set<String> updatedFields)` gets executed because of the around advice in the repository aspect.

The aspect that monitors all writing to private fields in the demo package:

```
@Aspect
public class SetterAspect {

    private UpdatableDtoManager updatableDtoManager = 
        UpdatableDtoManager.INSTANCE;

    @Pointcut("set(private * demo.*.*)")
    public void setterMethod() {}

    @AfterReturning("setterMethod()")
    public void afterSetMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        String fieldName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        updatableDtoManager.updateObjectWithUpdatedField(
                fieldName, joinPoint.getTarget());      
    }
}
```

The repository aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class UpdatableDtoRepositoryAspect {

    private UpdatableDtoManager updatableDtoManager = 
        UpdatableDtoManager.INSTANCE;

    @Pointcut("execution(void demo.DtoRepository.update(*)) " +
            "&& args(object)")
    public void updateMethodInRepository(Object object) {}

    @Around("updateMethodInRepository(object)")
    public void aroundUpdateMethodInRepository(
            ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, Object object) {

        Set<String> updatedFields = 
            updatableDtoManager.getUpdatedFieldsForObject(object);

        if (updatedFields.size() > 0) {
            ((DtoRepository<Object>)joinPoint.getTarget()).
                updatePerson(object, updatedFields);
        } else {

            // Returns without calling the repository.
            System.out.println("Nothing to update");
        }
    }   
}
```

Finally, the two helper classes used by the aspects:

```
public enum UpdatableDtoManager {

    INSTANCE;

    private Map<Object, UpdatedObject> updatedObjects = 
        new HashMap<Object, UpdatedObject>();

    public void updateObjectWithUpdatedField(
            String fieldName, Object object) {
        if (!updatedObjects.containsKey(object)) {
            updatedObjects.put(object, new UpdatedObject());
        }

        UpdatedObject updatedObject = updatedObjects.get(object);
        if (!updatedObject.containsField(fieldName)) {
            updatedObject.add(fieldName);
        }
    }

    public Set<String> getUpdatedFieldsForObject(Object object) {
        UpdatedObject updatedObject = updatedObjects.get(object);

        final Set<String> updatedFields;
        if (updatedObject != null) {
            updatedFields = updatedObject.getUpdatedFields();
        } else {
            updatedFields = Collections.emptySet();
        }

        return updatedFields;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class UpdatedObject {

    private Map<String, Object> updatedFields = 
        new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public boolean containsField(String fieldName) {
        return updatedFields.containsKey(fieldName);
    }

    public void add(String fieldName) {
        updatedFields.put(fieldName, fieldName);        
    }

    public Set<String> getUpdatedFields() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(
                updatedFields.keySet());
    }
}
```

My example does all the update logic with aspects. If all the DTOs implemented an interface that returns a `Set<String>`, you could have avoided the last aspect.

I hope this answered your question!

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, one approach is to use some form of byte code manipulation (e.g. [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/), BCEL) or a higher level AOP library sit on top of one of these tools, e.g. [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/), JBoss AOP.

Note: most JDO libraries do this for handling persistence.

Here is an example using javassist:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}

public static void rewritePersonClass() throws NotFoundException, CannotCompileException {
    ClassPool pool = ClassPool.getDefault();
    CtClass ctPerson = pool.get("Person");
    CtClass ctSet = pool.get("java.util.LinkedHashSet");

    CtField setField = new CtField(ctSet, "updatedFields", ctPerson);
    ctPerson.addField(setField, "new java.util.LinkedHashSet();");

    CtMethod method = ctPerson.getDeclaredMethod("setFirstName");
    method.insertBefore("updatedFields.add(\"firstName\");");

    ctPerson.toClass();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    rewritePersonClass();

    Person p = new Person();
    p.setFirstName("foo");

    Field field = Person.class.getDeclaredField("updatedFields");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Set<?> s = (Set<?>) field.get(p);

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dynamic Proxy Classes](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) and get the event before the call of `setFirstName` and other methods `set...`, determine field name with `method.substring(3)` => "FirstName", And put it in `setFirstName`.